# Is it okay to purchase Microsoft Office using an account previously used to sign in to a pirated version?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-account

I had used my Microsoft account to sign in to pirated versions of Microsoft Office products earlier. But, now I have decided to buy the original Office 365 using that account.

- Is it okay to use the same account, or should I use a different account?
- If I use the same account to sign in to the original MS Office now, will it cause any problem to me with my credit card info or any other private data as the account was previously used with a cracked version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you login to the Office Site and use the Buy function and enter a good credit card, then you should be fine.

1. Microsoft does not hold grudges or misuse information you supply.
2. You should uninstall the Office suite you have and restart. Then install the new download with the new Key.

You should be fine from here on in.